# Line under curve on the interval (proof)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

What is the easiest way how to prove that $3x+y=1$ is under $y=(1-x)^{3}$ without drawing graph? I mean by using some matematical technique. It is enough for interval $[-1,1]$. Thank you for advice.

Comment: It's better to write the line is under the curve on the interval.  The range of a cubic function and a linear function on $\Bbb R$ is $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$3x+y=1$ can be written as $y=1-3x$

We have to solve
$$1-3x<(1-x)^3$$
Expand and rearrange
$$1-3x<1-3x+3x^2-x^3$$
$$x^3-3x^2<0$$
$$x^2(x-3)<0$$
$$x<3$$
The line is under the curve for $x<3$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

You have to prove that the graph of $y=(1-x)^3$ is over the graph of $y=1-3x$ over $x \in [-1,1]$. It suffices to prove that
$$
\begin{split}
(1-x)^3 &\ge 1-3x \\
1 - 3x + 3x^2 - 3x^3 &\ge 1 - 3x \\
3x^2 - 3x^3 &\ge 0
\end{split}
$$
Can you finish?